# open menuitem on button click OpenERP

Tags: python, button, module, menuitem, openerp-7

I am trying to get behavior of `menuitem` in button click of OpenERP. The button that I have implemented opens search page, but it never goes to search menu item that i have created. In search menuitem i have Product Search, Location Search and Employee search. But clicking opens the search form bnut never updates the left portion of screen. For reference i am pasting images.

[image]
the above image is screenshot when i click on `Search Product` menuitem from top menu strip.

[image]
And this screenshot is when i click on search button.

I want the behavior of button as shown in first image.

So far my search code is:

```
def search_click (self,cr,uid,ids,context):
    return {
           'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
           'res_model': 'target model name',
           'view_type': 'form',
           'view_mode': 'form',
}
```

My View xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
<!--########################################Model -->
    <record id="home_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
               <field name="name">home.form</field>
               <field name="model">home.form</field>          
               <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
               <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <form string="FORM DATA" version="7.0"  create="false" edit="false" save="false">    
                    <button colspan="4" string="Search" name="search_click" type="action"/>
                  </form>
               </field>
       </record>



<!--#######################################Dealer-->
<record id="home_new_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Home</field>
            <field name="res_model">home.form</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="res_id">20</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="home_form_view"/>
</record>
<record id="home_new_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field eval="3" name="sequence"/>       
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="home_form_view"/>    
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="home_new_action"/>
</record>

 <!--#######################################-->

        <menuitem id="myhome" name="Home" sequence="0" />
    <menuitem id="myhome_menu" name=" " parent="myhome" />
    <menuitem action="home_new_action" id="homeform0_menu" name="Home" parent="myhome_menu"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Kindly guide me to right direction, as i am clueless now.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

```
tree_view_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'module_name', 'external_id_of_tree_view')
form_view_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'module_name', 'external_id_of_form_view')

return {
       'name': ('Execute Your Action'),
       'view_type': 'form',
       'res_model': 'model_name',
       'view_id': False,
       'context':context,
       'views': [(tree_view_id and tree_view_id[1] or 0, 'tree'), (form_view_id and form_view_id[1] or 0, 'form')],
       'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
       'target': 'current',
       'nodestroy': True
   }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please paste more details here to understand better your situation, please paste xml files content. Want to show action and form view.

Comment: I am not sure whether it works or not,
Find the action which is binded with Search Product menu and give that module name and action name into your button name.
<button colspan="4" string="Search" name="%modulename.actionname)d" type="action"/>